# Breaking out of a function with :connect using an if condition

Tags: function, loops, lua, roblox

I'm trying to use a boolean variable enterFinished to break out of the of the function keypad once the enter.MouseClick:connect() is finished.

```
function keypad(state)
    local enterFinished = false
     enter.MouseClick:Connect(function()
        if state == "unlock" then
            enterPressed = true
            local x = keyPressed(input)
            enterPressed = false
            table.clear(input)
            if x == pin then
                atmScreen.Text = ("Pin Correct!")
                enterFinished = true
            else
                atmScreen.Text = ("Pin Incorrect! Please reenter pin!")
            end
        elseif state == "choice" then
            print("choice")
        end
    end)    
    for i, v in pairs(folder:GetChildren()) do
        if enterFinished == true then
            print(enterFinished)
            return(nil)
        end 
        v.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
            table.insert(input,i)
            keyPressed(input)
        end)
    end
end
```

The if condition is only running once and whenever i try put it in a loop the code crashes or doesn't work.

Comment: which if condition?

Comment: @user253751 the if condition in the for loop. i did a small mistake while writing this post, sorry

Comment: from the beginning to the end of the for loop, `enterFinished` doesn't change, so why would doing the `if` more times be any different than doing it once?

Comment: @user253751 does `enterFinished` not change inside the `enter.MouseClick:Connect(function()` at  `enterFinished = true`

Comment: no, that just sets up the function to call later when someone clicks the mouse

Comment: You seem to be new to programming; you should know the computer runs the instructions in order from top to bottom unless you say otherwise (e.g. if statements and loops)`. This connect thing is an "unless you say otherwise". The code in the connect thing does not run straight away - it runs later, when the user clicks the mouse.

Comment: @user253751 my intention is to have the code running until the user clicks the enter button and then the whole function breaks, ie: the it keeps looping till the user clicks

Comment: the game won't process button clicks until the last code ends. It won't start running code while other code is already running.